# how to hide multidimensional list representing matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, operators

How can I hide a multidimensional list representing a matrix in MyMatrix class using a double underscore `__`?

```
class MyMatrix:
   height = 0
   width = 0
   data = tuple()

   def __init__(self, data):
       self.height = len(data)
       self.width = len(data[0])
       self.data = data

   def __getitem__(self, item):
       return self.data.__getitem__(item)

   def add(mat1, mat2):
       if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
           print("The matrices are not the same size!")
           return

       rows = []
       for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
           row = []
           for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
               row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])

           rows.append(tuple(row))
       return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot really “hide” anything. There is no concept of private variables (unlike Java or C++), because it wasn’t deemed necessary, and it would violate Python’s design principles.

If an identifier (variable or method) begins with two underscores, Python performs “name mangling” on it, i.e. when class `foo` contains a variable `__bar`, that name is actually replaced with `_foo__bar`. This isn’t meant to hide anything, though, because you can still access it with the mangled name. Rather, the purpose of this mechanism is to avoid name collisions when subclassing, because the class name becomes part of the identifier.

You might want to look up so-called properties. In your sample code, the `data` variable could be implemented as a property. See the [description of the property class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in the Python library reference.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a well-formed question. What do you mean when you say "hide"?

You can certainly replace the tuple representation of the matrix with a list representation of the matrix, but that isn't really hiding anything.

You can change `data` to be `__data` or `__data__`. But it will still be visible in the source code, and will still be publicly accessible to code outside the class definition. Again, not really hiding anything.

Also double underscores in class definitions are usually reserved for special methods, things like constructors and operator overloads.